# How can I use a dropdown select box to trigger this javascript instead of onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this JS at the bottom of a page that enables a user to sort elements with the class "grid-product-box" by various attributes the element is tagged with.

Works great but at the top of my page I have buttons for "Sort by price (low-high)", "Sort by name" etc which have IDs (#pricelh, #productname etc) and when clicked trigger the function you see below.

How could I create a dropdown select which would trigger this instead of a click? It could be as soon as the option is chosen from the dropdown or after a click of a "sort" button.

I have played around with the onChange handler but just end up breaking the script.

```
<SCRIPT>
var t;
    (function($) {

        $("#pricelh").click(function() {
            $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "productprice", digits: true});
        });
        $("#pricehl").click(function() {
            $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "productprice", digits: true, order: "desc"});
        });
        $("#productname").click(function() {
            $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "productname", ignoreCase: true});
        });
        $("#manufacturername").click(function() {
            $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "manufacturername", ignoreCase: true});
        });
        $("#sortOptions").click(function() {
            clearTimeout(t);
            $("#selectList option:gt(0)").qsort();
            showSortMessage();
        });
        $("#sortOptionsDesc").click(function() {
            clearTimeout(t);
            $("#selectList option:gt(0)").qsort({order: "desc"});           
            showSortMessage();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your select box is like this:

```
<select id="sortOptions">
    <option value="productprice">Price</option>
    <option value="productprice_desc">Price descending</option>
    <option value="productname">Name</option>
    <option value="manufacturername">Manufacturer</option>
</select>
```

You can create a map which maps these values to sort settings:

```
var sort_options = {
    productprice: {attr: "productprice", digits: true},
    productprice_desc: {attr: "productprice", digits: true, order: "desc"},
    productname: {attr: "productname", ignoreCase: true},
    manufacturername: {attr: "manufacturername", ignoreCase: true}
};
```

Then the event handler would be:

```
$('#sortOptions').change(function() {
    $(".grid-product-box").qsort(sort_options[this.value]);
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic, nice and clean and simple Felix... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selecteditem" onchange="[javascript here]">
```

This will work and you can get the `select value` using the `id`.

Maybe post what was wrong with your use of `select onchange`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectbox").change(function() {
 if($(this).val() == 'pricelh') {
   $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "productprice", digits: true});
    });
 } else if($(this).val() == 'pricehl') {
   $(".grid-product-box").qsort({attr: "productprice", digits: true, order: "desc"});
    });
 }
 // other functions
});
```

Think you can use this